# Play Framework non-parametrized map deserialization

Tags: java, dictionary, serialization, playframework

I have an interesting issue while trying to deserialize non-parametrized map in java 11 from JSON in Play 2.8.
Here is my DTO-class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.*;
import play.libs.Json;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonSerialize
@JsonDeserialize
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyDTO {
    private Map definition;
   }
```

If definition contains inner maps they are deserialized into scala.collections.immutabe.Map$Map2 and throws ClassCastException if I try something like

```
Map definition = (Map) myDTO.getDefinition(); // as I realized because of immutabe collection in scala
```

I hardcoded casting using scala.jdk.javaapi.CollectionConvertersCollectionConverters:

```
 Map meta =  CollectionConverters.asJava((scala.collection.immutable.Map)flow.getDefinition().get("metadata"));
```

The question is how can I configure deserialization into Java classes in Play.

Comment: Not clear: you use a Scala collection type in Java code? Why?

Comment: I have JSON-object like {"map1":{"map2":{...}}, "prop1":"...", ...} and the first map is deserialized into a normal regular java.util.Map<Object,Object> and map2 being an Object is casted to scala map, but I vant it to be java map

Comment: Sounds strange, show us the code you use to deserialize and the imports.

Comment: Added imports and annotations to code. Deserialization is Play embedded Json deserialization